Why are the COM interface types in the `windows` crate not `Send`?
As I understand it, COM objects have a "threadedness" that is associated with them when they are created. If an object needs to be handled on a certain thread, then method calls against that object will automatically be proxied. If this is true, then why is windows_core::IUnknown: !Send (and by extension, every COM interface in the windows crate)?
I understand that not every COM interface performs synchronization, which means that some objects will be !Sync, but I don't understand why they aren't all Send.

Presumably it's because IUnknown contains a NonNull, which is itself !Send, and IUnknown doesn't have an unsafe impl of Send. I don't know if the omission of this impl is intentional.

I'm not sure exactly what it means for rust, but concerning COM, to make it simple, it's not the interface (interfaces are just binary contracts) that declares how it behaves with regards to threading (objects can be marked as "apartment", "free", "both", etc.), but it's the object that serves it. So at code declaration level, you can't assume nothing in that matter.

"If an object needs to be handled on a certain thread, then method calls against that object will automatically be proxied." - That's incorrect. Marshaling is explicit rather than automatic. Marking IUnknown as !Send prevents the raw interface pointer from traveling across apartments (or threads that aren't in an apartment altogether). This doesn't entirely inhibit passing interfaces across apartments. You can use AgileReference to wrap an interface and have threading requirements verified at run time.
